# When is a linear map between Banach spaces one-to-one?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. Suppose $T: X \rightarrow Y$ is a bounded linear map. What are some sufficient conditions for $T$ to be one-to-one?

Comment: Simple one: the kernel of $T$ is trivial. But I'm guessing you already know that one!

Comment: If we have to give a satisfactory answer to this question we should know how you answer the following question: let $f:\mathbb  R \to \mathbb R$ be a function. What are some sufficient conditions for $f$ to be one-to-one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such condition is that the range of $T^*$ is dense in $X^*$.

Comment: I was about to say that should be weak* dense. But no, of course it follows that norm dense is sufficient - someone should mention that weak* dense is necessary and sufficient...